# How to pass variable in nested json of request body

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass a variable to my request body which has a nested json but not able to do so.

```
 Given path 'url'
 * request {abc:'ab',pqrs:'{"mno":"data","ijk":"data"}',dcb:'tata'} // Double quotes are required for 'pqrs' because thats the format of the service.
 When method post
 Then status 200
 * def test = response.lmn
 * print lmn
 * def browser = Java.type('file path') 
 * def testing = browser.do(parameter) // 'do' function will call a java file which will return a String parameter
 * print testing 


Given path 'url'
 * def nested = {uvw:"value",xyz:'#(testing)',ght:} //We tried storing nested variable in json format but that didn't work.
 * request { abc:'ab',pqr:'#(nested)',dcb:'tata' }
 When method post
 Then status 200
```

After hitting above request getting error as "Invalid pqr object". Please suggest solution.

Comment: Hi , I have accepted the answer of last question, please suggest for above question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making basic mistakes in forming JSON, that's all. For example, the `ght` field has nothing after it above. I'll just focus on the second part of your script. You can paste the below into a `Scenario` and see it work, by the way - this is a good tip: you can experiment like this quickly without making HTTP requests in a separate file.

```
* json testing = '{"helo":"world","test":"done"}'
* def nested = { uvw: 'value', xyz: '#(testing)', ght: null }
* def temp = { abc: 'ab', pqr: '#(nested)', dcb: 'tata' }
* print temp
```

And the output is:

```
[print] {
  "abc": "ab",
  "pqr": {
    "uvw": "value",
    "xyz": {
      "helo": "world",
      "test": "done"
    },
    "ght": null
  },
  "dcb": "tata"
}
```

So everything is working as expected.

Edit: showing how you can take a string and convert it back to JSON if needed. Please refer to the doc on [type-conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion) normally you don't need it, but looks like you do.

Comment: Sorry the 'ght' has a value I missed to add it.

Comment: Hi Peter Thanks for the reply.  In my case testing is a json string so it's like testing ={'helo':'world','test':'#(done)'} and not a string as seen in your example.
While printing  its giving an array and we need it to be json object.

Comment: I tried converting String to JSON it didn't work. Below is my request please have a look

* def nested = {'data4':'ehjfberhjbf','data5': '#(parameter)'} // Where parameter is a variable and it contains a string which is returned by Java file.
* request { data:'data1',data2:'#(nested)',data3:'data' } 

Now while hitting this I am getting error as "Invalid data2 object"

Comment: @Rahul sorry, I don't think you have read the doc at all, kindly try again. Please take the help of someone near you who knows JS. If you are still stuck we will need a complete working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - all the best !