# Cannot identify proper format for a json request body stored and used in csv file for use in a karate scenario

Tags: json, api, format, karate

Am having trouble identifying the propert format to store a json request body in csv format, then use the csv file value in a scenario.

This works properly within a scenario:
And request '{"contextURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321","individuals":[{"individualURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321:individual:12345678","name":{"firstName":"NUNYA","lastName":"BIDNESS"},"dateOfBirth":"1980-03-01","address":{"streetAddressLine1":"1 Myplace","streetAddressLine2":"","city":"LANDBRANCH","countrySubdivisionCode":"WV","postalCode":"25506","countryCode":"USA"},"objectType":"INDIVIDUAL"},{"individualURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321:individual:23456789","name":{"firstName":"NUNYA","lastName":"BIZNESS"},"dateOfBirth":"1985-03-01","address":{"streetAddressLine1":"1 Myplace","streetAddressLine2":"","city":"BRANCHLAND","countrySubdivisionCode":"WV","postalCode":"25506","countryCode":"USA"},"objectType":"INDIVIDUAL"}]}'

However, when stored in csv file as follows (I've tried quite a number other formatting variations)

'{"contextURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321","individuals":[{"individualURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321:individual:12345678","name":{"firstName":"NUNYA","lastName":"BIDNESS"},"dateOfBirth":"1980-03-01","address":{"streetAddressLine1":"1 Myplace","streetAddressLine2":"","city":"LANDBRANCH","countrySubdivisionCode":"WV","postalCode":"25506","countryCode":"USA"},"objectType":"INDIVIDUAL"},{"individualURN":"urn:com.myco.here:env:booking:reservation:0987654321:individual:23456789","name":{"firstName":"NUNYA","lastName":"BIZNESS"},"dateOfBirth":"1985-03-01","address":{"streetAddressLine1":"1 Myplace","streetAddressLine2":"","city":"BRANCHLAND","countrySubdivisionCode":"WV","postalCode":"25506","countryCode":"USA"},"objectType":"INDIVIDUAL"}]}',

and used in scenario as:

And request requestBody

my test returns an "javascript evaluation failed: " & the json above & :1:63 Missing close quote ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 63

Can you please identify correct formatting or the usage errors I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Please make your question more readable putting code in code blocks ( {} icon in editor). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just use a basic CSV library behind the scenes. I suggest you roll your own Java helper class that does whatever processing / pre-processing you need.

Do read this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

I can't make sense of your JSON but if you are trying to fit JSON into CSV, sorry - that's not a good idea. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449166/143475