# Scenario outline examples from .txt file (Each line in the .txt file is a JSON)

Tags: karate, data-driven-tests

I want to send `POST` requests with the the request body (JSON ) from a `.txt` file. Each line in the `.txt` file is a `JSON` request and I want to send the request as is for each line.

Here is my feature file:

Scenario Outline: Read from txt
* url blah blah
Given request 
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
When method post
Then status 201

```
Examples:
|Req|
|read('Requests.txt')|
```

Here is my sample .txt file

```
{"merch":"asf","name":"twin","currencyCode":"USD","amount":4000}
{"merch":"are","name":"pdf","currencyCode":"USD","amount":2500}
```

Could you please guide how I could accomplish this. I tried using `.csv`, but the entire `JSON` is not read in that case for each line. I am looking for a very simple way of sending the request one by one for each line in the `.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a one-time bit of Java code that loops over the lines and gives you a JSON array and then just use that. You may be even able to do it in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035825/143475).

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64393794/143475

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.